# Recursive polymer elements

Tags: javascript, recursion, polymer

I have a nested array of javascript objects like this:

```
[
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
            {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
                {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
                {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
            ]},
            {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to define the template section of a polymer element that will render a nested list like this where you don't know how deep the recursion might go. How could I, for example, render this recursive object as follows using polymer expressions in a template?

```
<ul>
  <li>hello (1)
    <ul>
      <li>hello (3)
        <ul>
          <li>hello (4)
            <ul>
              <li>hello (5)</li>
              <li>hello (6)</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>hello (7)</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>hello (2)
    <ul>
      <li>hello (8)</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recursion works just as you'd expect it to with Polymer. Simply declare an element, and then use that element within its template :)

```html
<script src='//www.polymer-project.org/components/platform/platform.js'></script>
<link rel='import' href='//www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html'>


<polymer-element name='tree-node' attributes='nodeData' noscript>
  <template>
    <ul>
      <li>{{nodeData.title}} ({{nodeData.id}})</li>
      <template repeat='{{child in nodeData.children}}'>
        <tree-node nodeData='{{child}}'></tree-node>
      </template>
    </ul>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<script>
  var data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
      {id: 3, title: 'hello', parent: 1, children: [
          {id: 4, title: 'hello', parent: 3, children: [
              {id: 5, title: 'hello', parent: 4},
              {id: 6, title: 'hello', parent: 4}
          ]},
          {id: 7, title: 'hello', parent: 3}
      ]}
    ]},
    {id: 2, title: 'hello', parent: 0, children: [
        {id: 8, title: 'hello', parent: 2}
    ]}
  ];

  data.forEach(function(nodeData) {
    var treeNode = document.createElement('tree-node');
    treeNode.nodeData = nodeData;
    document.body.appendChild(treeNode);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<polymer-element name="scary-cuisine" attributes="myArray">
  <template>
    <ul>
      <template repeat="{{foo in myArray}}">
        <li>{{foo.title}} {{foo.id}}
          <ul>
            <template repeat="{{bar in foo.children}}">
              <li>{{bar.title}} {{bar.id}}
                <ul>
                  <template repeat="{{foobar in bar.children}}">
                    <li>{{foobar.title}} {{foobar.id}}
                      <ul>
                        <template repeat="{{barfoo in foobar.children}}">
                          <li>{{barfoo.title}} {{barfoo.id}}</li>
                        </template>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                  </template>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </template>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </template>
    </ul>
    <style>
      :host {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }
    </style>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('scary-cuisine', {
      created: function() {
        this.myArray = [];
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<scary-cuisine myArray="[{'id':'1', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'0', 'children':[{'id':'3', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'1', 'children': [{'id':'4', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'3', 'children':[{'id':'5', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'4'}, {'id':'6', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'4'}]}, {'id':'7', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'3'}]}]}, {'id':'2', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'0', 'children':[{'id':'8', 'title':'hello', 'parent':'2'}]}]"></scary-cuisine>
```

Comment: will that work "where you don't know how deep the recursion might go" ?

Comment: Read the bit from "You can use the ref attribute to define recursive templates, such as tree structures:".

https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#importing-templates-by-reference

Comment: @dandavis hit the nail on the head. This solution only solves it for when you know how deep the tree is. I would like a more elegant solution that doesn't require a nested template for each potential level.